# What is the query limit for Google's Suggest API?

Tags: google-suggest

Does anyone know the query limit for this undocumented/unofficial google api?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There doesn't appear to be a limit on the suggest api. I've made ~15,000 in the past hour without any disruptions.

Comment: hi, Im interested in using suggest api. can you please tell me instruction on how I could use it too? THank you.

Comment: @ricky Google suggest now uses a different url. Here is the old one, it still works http://google.com/complete/search?output=json&q=QWERY

Answer (score 0):

After 50.000th query I am getting 403 error response saying :

> We're sorry... but your computer or
>   network may be sending automated
>   queries. To protect our users, we
>   can't process your request right now.

Comment: Approx how many queries per hour were you running? I ran a over 500k queries (months ago), but at only ~25-40k queries/per hour.

Answer (score 0):

In my case afther ~100 queries google stops to give response 
i call it by json_decode(utf8_decode(file_get_contents('http://suggestqueries.google.com/complete/search?output=firefox&client=firefox&hl=pl-PL&q='.urlencode($keyword))),true);